# Getting RabbitMQ authentication failing even with cookie is set

Tags: rabbitmq

I have recently installed rabbitmq with ErlanOTP on Windows 10 running on  lattePanda

I ran rabbitmqctl status and got the following error:

> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.5\sbin>rabbitmqctl status
> Status of node rabbit@DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF ...
> Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.
>
> Most common reasons for this are:
>
> - Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
> - CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
> - Target node is not running
>
> In addition to the diagnostics info below:
>
> - See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on http://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
> - Consult server logs on node rabbit@DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF
>
> DIAGNOSTICS
>
> attempted to contact: ['rabbit@DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF']
>
> rabbit@DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF:
>
> - connected to epmd (port 4369) on DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF
> - epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
> - TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
> - Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie
>
> Current node details:
>
> - node name: 'rabbitmqcli2@DESKTOP-V6GQ6RF'
> - effective user's home directory: C:\Users\LattePanda
> - Erlang cookie hash: 8Kq9f/AaeixMvahU4G2v8A==

How can I get RabbitMQ up and running?

While trouble-shooting I discovered this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/a6sqrAUX_Fg

and set the environment variable to Erlang Cookie I found in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.erlang.cookie` but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to copy the cookie from the correct location. [This document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html#erlang-cookie) explains where it is located based on Erlang version and Windows version. You don't mention which Erlang version you are using, but I suspect you will want to copy the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie` file to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.erlang.cookie`. You should not have to set any environment variables so if you have, I recommend removing them and restarting your server.